# Plotly Dash: dash_bootstrap_components.Collapse does not collapse

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to implement a `dash_bootstrap_components.Collapse` in my `dash` app, but there is an issue with its behavior. Here the code, I do not wrote it on my own, I simply copied it from the `dash_bootstrap_components.Collapse` [documentation](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/collapse/):

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dbc.Button('Open collapse',
                                  id = 'collapse-button',
                                  className = 'mb-3',
                                  color = 'primary'),
                       dbc.Collapse(dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody('This content is hidden in the collapse')),
                                    id = 'collapse')])


@app.callback(Output('collapse', 'is_open'),
              [Input('collapse-button', 'n_clicks')],
              [State('collapse', 'is_open')])
def toggle_collapse(n, is_open):
    if n:
        return not is_open
    return is_open

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

When I click on the button, nothing happens.
I tryied to figure out where is the problem, I discovered that:

- `n` in the `app.callback` is initialized to `None`, after one click it becomes `1`, then it increases by `1` with the number of button clicks, correclty
- `is_open` in the `app.callback` is initialized to `None`, after one click it still remains `None`, then after the second click become `True`, after third click `False` and so on

What can I do in order to make it work?

Version info:

```
Python                    3.7.0
dash                      1.12.0
dash-bootstrap-components 0.10.1
dash-core-components      1.10.0
dash-html-components      1.0.3
dash-renderer             1.4.1
dash-table                4.7.0
plotly                    4.7.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you link the Boostrap stylesheet your code will work as it is.

```py
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
```